# Similarity between $2$ sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two sets $S_1=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $S_2\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

- $Intersection (I) = 4$
- Number of non-equal elements (N) = $5$

I am trying to find a way to combine the `intersection` and `number of non-equal elements` to compute the similarity between the two sets. The higher the number of non-equal elements the lower the similarity

---

`Solution (Gerry Myerson)` Let $I$ be the size of the intersection, $N$ the number of non-equal elements.  The similarity between $S_1$ and $S_2$ is then  $I~/~(N+1)$

Comment: Let $I$ be the size of the intersection, $N$ the number of non-equal elements. You could use $I/(N+1)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just have one problem. How can I normalize it between $0$and $1$. because suppose that $I = 6$ and $N = 2$ it wont be between $0$ and $1$ that's what i am trying to figure out now.

Comment: If that's what you want, please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gerry suggested:

$$sim(S_1,S_2) = |S_1 \cap S_2| ~/~ (|S_1 {\tiny \triangle}~ S_2| + 1),$$

where the triangle is the symmetric difference. We can try to normalize it as follows:

$$norm(S_1,S_2) = sim(S_1,S_2) ~/~ |S_1 \cup S_2|.$$

Of course, whenever $|S_1 \cup S_2| = 0$, we let $norm(S_1,S_2) = 0$.

Comment: Is it possible to normalize it between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: I've updated the answer. See if that's what you want.